# Сборка проекта в Atmel Studio с выводом на консоль

Tags: atmel-studio

Сборка проекта Atmel Studio 7 осуществляется командной строкой:

```
atmelstudio.exe foo.cproj /build debug /out log.txt
```

Сообщения во время сборки пишутся в `log.txt`, а хотелось бы видеть их в консоли (просто не указывать `/out log.txt` не помогает).

Comment: А Вы не пробовали ` /out STDOUT`?

Comment: @IgorSergeevich попробовал только что, выводит в файл с именем STDOUT в текущей директории

Comment: Вот как в файл из терминала вывести, вообще не вопрос, а вот в терминал, интересно... А если попробовать открыть вкладку терминала, найти его `PID` и попробовать как-то залить в него?